# Does $f(x) = -\sin(2x)$ have two integrals?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I found $\cos^2(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ which happily differ by the constant of $1$ though I've also found $\frac 12 \cos(2x)$, which both of the former diverge from by a sinusoidal function, what's wrong with the calculation?

Comment: $\dfrac12\cos(2x)=\cos^2x-\dfrac12=\dfrac12-\sin^2x$

Comment: You have discovered that a function can usually be written in many different forms (and sometimes it but is not easy to recognize that they are equal)

Comment: $\cos^2(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ don't *differ* by the constant $1$, they *sum* to it.

Answer (score 1):

All [expressions differ](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+%7Bcos(x)%5E2,-sin(x)%5E2,cos(2x)%2F2%7D) only by a constant. That is why the derivative of each expression does agree with your initial function, since the derivative of a constant is zero.

Another way of looking at these solution is that each solution is an indefinite integral of the given function.

Answer (score 0):

sorry my bad, `-0.5*cos(2x)` is the problematic function, which flips the sign for all the parts in the equation above which makes them different function which I think do not apply

Comment: It might be better to register your original account and then edit your question, rather than posting this as an answer from a second (registered) account.

Comment: sorry, it told me I supposed to have 50 reputation to do that, now it's fine, thanks for pointing it out though